# How to implement multiple tagging in ionic 3 or angular 4

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, ionic3

i want to implement the `multiple` `tagging` i don't know any specific package for this.

i want to have multiple `tagging` for  this set of `data`.

```
skills = ['javascript','angular 4','css','php',..............];
```

i want to have similar `multiple` `tagging` like `select2` here is demo : https://select2.org/tagging

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ionic3 you can use the below mentioned package of npm

```
npm install ng2-tag-input
```

After installing the package, you need to add the dependencies in module file like this,

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TagInputModule } from 'ng2-tag-input';

imports: [
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     TagInputModule
  ]
```

Now for example, if you have one component called home then in your home.ts file you need to add the code like this,

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    skills = ['javascript','angular 4','css','php'];

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

 }

}
```

and finally in your template file you need to write something like this,

**home.html**

```
<tag-input [(ngModel)]='skills'></tag-input>
```

Comment: sir , i followed every step accordingly but i'm getting this `error` `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'tag-input' is not a known element: 1. If 'tag-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'tag-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" <ion-content padding> [ERROR ->]<tag-input [(ngModel)]="skills"></tag-input> </ion-content> "): ng:///TagsPageModule/TagsPage.html@16:4 Error: Template parse errors: 'tag-input' is not a known element: 1. I`

Comment: First uninstall the package and then try to install the package using npm install ng2-tag-input --save this command

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, i have `unistalled` and `installed` but getting the same `error`

Comment: @EaB : cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)
   @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
global packages:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
System:
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.11.4
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Linux 4.4
Misc:
   backend : legacy

Comment: @EaB: Above is my ionic info in which above mentioned code is working for me. Please compare it with your ionic info

Comment: @EaB you can also try by adding FormModule in your app.module.ts file like import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms' this and then add the dependency in import like imports: [FormsModule] this